# How to define mongodb ArrayField in Djongo's model

Tags: django, djongo

```
class question(models.Model):
    question_id = models.IntegerField()
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100))
```

ERROR:

```
packages\djongo\models\fields.py", line 116, in _validate_container
for field in self.model_container._meta._get_fields(reverse=False):
    AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I want to add a ArrayField in my models using djongo models. i hope 'tags' looks like ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3' ...]. But djongo requeirs model_container, but i only want an array contains strings, not a model ,please help~~

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar situation: wanted to create an IntegerField array. I solved it with this workaround:

Create an intermediate model which stores your field.

For example, for my use case (with integers that represent quantity by each second) I created a model called `Second` which holds an attribute called `data` of type `models.IntegerField()`:

```
class Second(models.Model):
    data = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ParentModel(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()

    by_second = models.ArrayField(
      model_container=Second
    )

    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

So I guess in your case you could use the same but changing `models.IntegerField()`by `models.CharField(max_length=100)`

I know it has been a long time since the question was asked, but I hope this helps someone having this issue :)